# renaming a column in a dataframe using a value from the global environment in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (summary_transposed_no_time) and I want to rename one of the columns to a name I have stored as a value.

summary_transposed_no_time looks like this:

```
       | A      | B      | C      | D
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
area_1 | 0.870  | 0.435  | 0.968  | 0.679
area_2 | 0.456  | 0.259  | 0.906  | 0.467
area_3 | 0.298  | 0.256  | 0.457  | 0.768
area_4 | 0.994  | 0.987  | 0.365  | 0.765
```

My value is called test and it is set to "B" so I have tried using the following code with no luck:

```
summary_transposed_no_time <- names(summary_transposed_no_time)[c(test_col)]<-c("test")
```

**Desire output**

```
       | A      | test   | C      | D
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
area_1 | 0.870  | 0.435  | 0.968  | 0.679
area_2 | 0.456  | 0.259  | 0.906  | 0.467
area_3 | 0.298  | 0.256  | 0.457  | 0.768
area_4 | 0.994  | 0.987  | 0.365  | 0.765
```

Comment: Hi Zheyuan Li - sorry I forgot to mention that the column will be in a different position each time I run the code so I cannot hard code the column position within the frame. Also, how do I input my tables within my questions so that they don't need any subsequent formatting? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need (I have replaced `summary_transposed_no_time` with `x`)

```
names(x)[match(test_col, names(x))] <- "test"
```

---

```
x <- trees[1:5, ]
#  Girth Height Volume
#1   8.3     70   10.3
#2   8.6     65   10.3
#3   8.8     63   10.2
#4  10.5     72   16.4
#5  10.7     81   18.8

names(x)[match("Girth", names(x))] <- "test"
#   test Height Volume
#1  8.3     70   10.3
#2  8.6     65   10.3
#3  8.8     63   10.2
#4 10.5     72   16.4
#5 10.7     81   18.8
```